# Can the prime number theorem be given in terms of d(x) or σ(x)?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Given according to Apostol's Introduction to Analytic Number Theorem p79, these relations satisfy equivalence to the Prime Number Theorem:

$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\pi(x)\ln(x)}{x}=1$

$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\theta(x)}{x}=1$

$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\psi(x)}{x}=1$

They are in terms of $\pi(x),\,\, \theta(x)\,\, and\,\, \psi(x)$, so can the same be done in terms of the divisor functions $d(x)$ or $\sigma(x)$ for the prime number theorem?

Comment: $d(n)$ varies between $2$ and *many*.   Severin Wigert proved $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\log d(n)}{\log n/\log\log n}=\log2$

Comment: @Henry thank you I'll look it up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Severin_Wigert